# Why CLH Lock need prev-Node in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, spinlock

This is a typical CLH-Lock in java:

```
public class CLHLock{  

    private final AtomicReference tail;

    // why we need this node?  
    private final ThreadLocal myPred;  

    private final ThreadLocal myNode;  

    public CLHLock() {  
        tail = new AtomicReference(new QNode());  
        myNode = new ThreadLocal() {  
            protected QNode initialValue() {  
                return new QNode();  
            }  
        };  

        myPred = new ThreadLocal();  
    }  

    public void lock() {  
        QNode node = myNode.get();  
        node.locked = true;  
        QNode pred = tail.getAndSet(node); 

        // this.myPred == pred 
        myPred.set(pred);  
        while (pred.locked) {  
        }  
    }  

    public void unlock() {  
        QNode node = myNode.get();  
        node.locked = false;  

        // this.myNode == this.myPred
        myNode.set(myPred.get());  
    }  

    private static class QNode {  
        volatile boolean locked;  
    }  
}
```

Why we need `myPred` Node, only two places used this variable:

1. `this.prev.set(pred);`
2. List item `this.node.set(this.prev.get());`

when we done, `this.prev == this.node == pred` ?

Maybe we can implements like this:

```
public class CLHLock {
    // Node tail
    private final AtomicReference<QNode> tail = new AtomicReference<>(new QNode());

    // ThreadLocal
    private final ThreadLocal<QNode> node = ThreadLocal.withInitial(QNode::new);

    public void lock() {
        QNode now = node.get();
        now.locked = true;

        // spin on pre-node
        QNode pre = tail.getAndSet(now);
        while (pre.locked) {
        }
    }

    public void unlock() {
        QNode now = node.get();
        now.locked = false;
    }

    class QNode {
        volatile boolean locked = false;
    }
}
```

What is the difference between the above two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second implementation is deadlock-prone.

Assume you have two threads, T1 and T2. T1 owns the lock and T2 waits for T1 to release it.

`T1.node.locked` is true, `T2.node.locked` is true, tail points to `T2.node` and T2 is spinning on `pre.locked`, which is T1's node.

Now T1 releases the lock (setting `T1.node.locked` to false) and right after this tries to acquire it again while T2 is preempted.
`T1.node.locked` becomes true again, but tail is `T2.node`, so T1 now is waiting for T2. And T2 is still waiting for the same node of T1 which is now locked! Deadlock.

First implementation protects you against it by reusing not current, but previous (predecessor) node, so such situations are not possible: either predecessor was null (then there is nothing to reuse) or not, then it's node is reused when it becomes unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

Second implemention does not work.
Assume Thread one owns the lock first,then it releases the lock.The tail is Thread one's node Now.But Thread one acquires the lock again,it will be found that Thread one will be spinning forever.Anyway just change the unlock method a little,the pred node will not be necessary.

```
public void unlock() {  
    QNode node = myNode.get();  
    node.locked = false;  

    // this.myNode == this.myPred
    myNode.set(new Node());  
}
```

It will work too.